# mySQL, changing table collation/charset does not cascade to changing columns collation/char set

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table with a lot of columns that I want to change from latin1_swedish_ci to one that accepts unicode.  This is a table that has been in production for a number of years.

I altered the table using workbench which generated this statement
`ALTER TABLE schema.tablename  CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 , COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ;`

when I run `show full columns from tablename` I still see all the varchar columns showing `latin_swedish_ci` as their collation. (mySQL 8.0.26)  Additionally I also get illegal mix of collation errors.

My expectation this change to cascade down to the columns such that previous columns would have there collation updated to match the table.  Was my assumption incorrect and a table's collation is not the same thing as a column's collation?  Is there a missing step?   If editing a table's collation does not have an effect on the column's collation, then what is the difference/purpose of having both a table collation and a column collation?  I imagine the solution in my situation would be to just 'update the column's collations' but that raises the question of why change the table collation?

thank you

Comment: I think columns can have their own collation so you need to change it for the columns themselves. Also make sure when inserting data the collation of that data matches the new collations of the columns you changed. `ALTER TABLE schema.tablename MODIFY COLUMN column_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;` might work, you'll have to do it for each column

Comment: so perhaps my real question lies in the mismatch where there is something about a tables collation vs a column's collation that I am missing, i can edit the quesiton to clarify that.  I see that you can alter a columns collation, i just dont understand why updating the table's doesnt change it.

Comment: I think after setting the tables collation it will be applied for new columns, but not existing ones

Comment: Also make sure to backup your data before applying any changes to columns, as a new collation might cause corrupt data etc when converting from the old one

Comment: that is a good suggestion @Mayfair, I cant find anything in the docs that states that but it is certainly testable to create new columns and see how they behave

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-table.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-column.html go into detail about this topic

Comment: Database charset/collation settings are just the default for new tables.  Table charset/collation settings are just the default for new column definitions.